# DynamoDB or RDS?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-rds

I keep going back and forth about choosing DynamoDB or RDS for my project. I understand they are 2 completely different kinds of DB systems, but I am not sure which one would be a better fit for my app. My app alerts users of certain events that happen VERY infrequently.

For instance, an employee may trigger an alert saying that there is an active shooter in the building, so my app needs to get the cell phone numbers of everyone in the company from the database and then use those numbers to send text messages. I just discovered that DynamoDB has a limit of 100 items when retrieving stuff from the database, which is a problem for me because I may have to retrieve 200 or 300 or even more phone numbers as quickly as possible.

In addition to this, the database would not be queried regularly. It would be queried rarely when someone needs to update a user's profile information. of course, it would be queried for users' cell phone numbers in an emergency and I need this to return the results as fast as possible.

It kind of sounds like DynamoDB may be an overkill, but I am not 100 % sure. On the other hand, It seems a PERFECT fit since it can query stuff really quickly, but the limit of 100 items per request just kills me.

To me, there isn't a clear answer in terms of what database system to choose. Based on this use case, what is the best DB option?

Comment: The limit of 100 items is only for the BatchGetItem request. If you instead use a Query request then there is no upper limit apart from a size limit of 1MB. But if you think you will exceed the size limit, then you can paginate your results using the `LastEvaluatedKey` from the response to get more items. But as @Vladimir suggests below, perhaps AWS pinpoint would be the tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You should use AWS pinpoint for that. Pinpoint has endpoints and segments.

- The endpoint is email, number... One person in the company can have multiple endpoints.
- The segment is a filtered list of endpoints. For example, you can filter endpoints by person title, or by company.
- You create Campaign based on segments, so each person in selected segments get email or SMS or both...

Regarding your example, you can create a dynamo DB trigger which will create/update/delete pinpoint endpoints.

AWS approach is not to scan dynamo DB to send group emails or SMS. Instead of that, the approach is to create segment and then create campaigns.